# android broadcast receiver to detect app in background change

Tags: android, background, broadcastreceiver, task

Is there anyway to capture when other application goes into background? Any broadcast receiver we can register to receive that event?

Comment: other application!!!! what other application?

Comment: If it is an application you can code to yes, otherwise, no (except in rare cases getting access to logcat logs).

Comment: You can't register a receiver to this. What you can do is check the state of that specific application whenever you want (every minute, hours, on an event, etc), you can get all the applications fro the packagemanager and check their state

Comment: That's what i found out as well. I created a service to monitor the application/package that i want to monitor using a timertask. But i don't think this is a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a backgroung service that periodically monitors the running services and if a new service comes up raises a flag.
Use this to get the list of running services:

```
    public List<String> getRunningServices(Context context){
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> serviceList = activityManager
                .getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        List<String> rServices = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < serviceList.size(); i++) {
            RunningServiceInfo serviceInfo = serviceList.get(i);
            ComponentName serviceName = serviceInfo.service;            
            rServices.add(serviceName.getClassName());      
        }
        return rServices;
   }
```

Comment: this is my current solution as well. I am thinking is there any other better way to receiver broadcast message instead of checking periodically.

Comment: I don't think there's any other way to monitor other background services.

Comment: By the way, do you know NDK can help on this topic?

Answer (score 1):

There are no broadcast `Intent`s regarding activities coming to or leaving the foreground, for obvious privacy reasons.